# create mongodb backup and upload to amazon s3

Tags: python, mongodb, shell, amazon-s3, backup

I was trying to create MongoDB backup and upload it to amazon s3. This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash  
#Force file syncronization and lock writes

mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"

MONGODUMP_PATH="/home/ubuntu/backup/mongodb"
MONGO_HOST="122.248.238.32"
MONGO_PORT="27017"
MONGO_DATABASE="eb"

TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M`
S3_BUCKET_NAME="MongodbBackup"
S3_BUCKET_PATH="mongodb-backups"


# Create backup
$MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE

# Add timestamp to backup
mv dump mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP
tar cf mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP

# Upload to S3
s3cmd put mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$S3_BUCKET_PATH/mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar


#Unlock databases writes
mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"
```

When I run this script, I am getting a response like this

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: admin
{
    "info" : "now locked against writes, use db.fsyncUnlock() to unlock",
    "seeAlso" : "http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/fsynccommand",
    "ok" : 1
}
mv: cannot stat `dump': No such file or directory
tar: mongodb-ip-10-145-167-183-2014-06-02-1055: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
WARNING: Module python-magic is not available. Guessing MIME types based on file extensions.
mongodb-ip-10-145-167-183-2014-06-02-1055.tar -> s3://MongodbBackup/mongodb-backups/mongodb-ip-10-145-167-183-2014-06-02-1055.tar  [1 of 1]
 10240 of 10240   100% in    1s     9.55 kB/s  done
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: admin
{ "ok" : 1, "info" : "unlock completed" }
```

How can i create backup and upload to s3 properly?

Comment: Don't keep the DB locked until you upload to S3. You should unlock as soon as the dump finishes

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE
```

with

```
cd $MONGODUMP_PATH
mongodump -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE
```